# RoR Devise create user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have 2 tables: contacts and users (Devise).
I would like to create a user each time an contact is created.
The contact belongs_to :user
The user has_one :contact

The following code in the contact.rb file creates the user when you add a new contact:

```
before_create :create_user

protected
def create_user
  self.user = User.new({ :email => self.email, :password => '123456' })
  return user.save
end
```

But, the contact field user_id (foreign key) isn't getting updated with the new user id.
How can accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
def create_user
  self.user = User.create({ :email => self.email, :password => '123456' })
end
```

My guess is that the association is not being registered because after the `User.new` call the object has not been saved to the database and has not been assigned an id attribute, and the id attribute is what is required to record the association. `User.create` initializes the object and saves it to the database in one step (assuming all validations pass).